# Create Multiple join query - Dapper

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

recently i'm working on an application and my instructor asked me to use Dapper as ORM. This is the first time to work on it. I want to create a join query for 3 tables and store the value in custom object.

Here are the tables :

```
public class Customer
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string fname { get; set; }
public string lname { get; set; }
public List<Orders> Order { get; set; }
}


public class Orders
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string code{ get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public  Customer Customer { get; set; }
public  Product Product  { get; set; }
}



public class Product
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string price { get; set; }
public  List<Orders> Order { get; set; }
}
```

This DTO Class:

```
public class CustomDTO
{
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
public string OrderName { get; set; }
public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store result executed from the dapper join query into CustomDTO

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you really need to supply more info in your post so people don't have to assume too much. 
From what you've said, *one possible approach* is this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"))
{
    connection.Open();

    string cmdTxt = @"SELECT o.name, c.name, p.name
        FROM Orders o
        INNER JOIN Customers c ON o.customerId = c.Id 
        INNER JOIN Products p ON o.productId = p.Id;";

    var results = await connection.QueryAsync<CustomDTO>(cmdTxt);

    if(results.Any()) {
        //do something with the list of `CustomDTO`
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Note: I'm assuming your Orders table has the relevant foreign keys.